# Take snapshot of video

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, thumbnails, snapshot

I'm trying to take snapshot of video and than save as thumbnail. I have found  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575311/how-can-i-save-first-frame-of-a-video-as-image) and have done as it's there. But i get this exception:

[WIN32Exception was unhandled by User-Code - The system cannot find the file specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmzVg.png)

what have I done wrong?

my code is here:

```
FFMPEG f = new FFMPEG();
f.GetThumbnail(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + unique), Server.MapPath("~/Thumbnails/" + unique.Remove(unique.IndexOf(".")) + ".jpg"), "1200x223");
```

and there's my [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWojn.png).

Comment: It clearly states that it can't find the file.

Comment: Okuma.Scott you're right but why? I think it should find that file

Comment: Have a look at [Server.MapPath"~"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/275781/2596334).

Comment: Also, no one can tell what that path will look like without a definition for "unique". Please read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong path of

> ffmpeg.exe

```
ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ffmpeg.exe");
```